# Spacing between Bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make sure that there is spacing between the buttons when i use the following piece of code

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron">
    <button ng-repeat="char in alphabet" ng-click="filterByAlphabet(char)">{{char}}</button>
    <br><br>         
    <span ng-repeat="genre in genres"> 
        <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="filterByGenre(genre)">{{genre}}</button>            
    </span>            

</div>
```

Comment: spacing between? Do you want them horizontal aligned? have you tried some custom CSS?

Comment: Use CSS to add spacing

Answer (score 5):

'btn-toolbar' does the trick in one fell swoop. No manual css'ing required

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <button id="button1" class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button>
    <button id="button2" class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button>
    <button id="button3" class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Bootstrap spacing, docs here --> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

This example uses the class 'mr-2' to add right margins to buttons

```
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" class="btn btn-primary">Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use css property margin

```
button { margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px } //change the value to see the effect and choose for yourself which value to keep
```

margin: *margin-top*  *margin-right*  *margin-bottom*  *margin-left* ;

Comment: we must explore bootstrap built in capabilities first if we use bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 1):

Set right margin on buttons:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="jumbotron">
    <button ng-repeat="char in alphabet" ng-click="filterByAlphabet(char)" style="margin-right: 10px;">{{char}}</button>
    <br><br>         
    <span ng-repeat="genre in genres"> 
        <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="filterByGenre(genre)" style="margin-right: 10px;">{{genre}}</button>            
    </span>            
</div>
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks d.coder - this addressed the margin question. Buttons are still however left aligned. How do i centre them on the page?

Comment: Why 'still', when you never mentioned you wanted them centre aligned in the first place? You should edit your question to include this.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of current output? I am not able to judge that exactly what changes will fix your problem.

Comment: d.coder - thanks for your support. I was able to just add a "text-center" on the container and got the desired out.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.capsule{
  padding: 0 30px;
 }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
  <span class="col-xs-4"> &nbsp; </span>
   <span class="capsule col-xs-2">
    <button ng-repeat="char in alphabet" ng-click="filterByAlphabet(char)">{{char}}</button>        
   </span>
   <span class="capsule col-xs-2" ng-repeat="genre in genres"> 
    <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="filterByGenre(genre)">{{genre}}</button>            
   </span>            

  </div>
```

i added one empty span to center the jumbo in the screen, also added "capsule" span to get space between the buttons.

Hope it helps!